# Restrict user from accessing any programs but one (win 10)

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, restrictions

I'm running Windows 10 and I have two separate accounts, mine (Administrator) and user 2 (local account). I want to restrict user 2 from accessing any programs save for a web browser and np++.

I looked it up and the method suggested is usually GPO restricted groups, however I'm not sure those are safe enough.

here's an [example of solution for earlier windows versions](https://superuser.com/questions/196100/how-to-restrict-apps-for-a-user-account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: You can do this using Assigned Access.

Left click on `Start`, then click `Settings`, then `Accounts`.

Now click `Family and other users`.  In `Other Users` click `Setup assigned access`.  Choose the account you want to restrict and then select the program you want to restrict the user to.  A guide is provided here: http://www.winbeta.org/news/setup-assigned-access-windows-10-kiosk-mode

Comment: I couldn't find any `Set Up Parental Controls` in the menu you're mentioning. [Here's my view](http://imgur.com/dMSU3IW.gif)

Comment: That is odd...  You can get to the options you need by a different route also.  I will add it to the answer above.

Comment: Ah, the answer I gave was for a different version.  I have updated the answer.  Let me know if this works.